# How to filter generic class for shim?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, shim

I have a generic class similar to following

```
public class HelperClass<T> where T : DBTable, new()
{
}
```

I have to shim this class but when I compile the code, I get warning.
I have added following line in .fakes

```
<pre lang="c#"><Add FullName="A.B.HelperClass" /></pre>
```

When I Set diagnostics = true,
it is trying to shim classes like HelperClass'1

How can I apply filter in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the class with the _`1_ form at the end?

Comment: Yes. I have tried. I have added line <Add FullName="A.B.HelperClass" />. But when I add type like <Add FullName="A.B.HelperClass<DBTable>>". This second line generates compile time error. Something like tag not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to generate shims for all versions of a generic type.

```
<ShimGeneration>
    </Clear>
    <Add TypeName="HelperClass`1"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

If you happen to also have a non-generic class of the same name, the above will not generate shims for it. If you wish to generate them for both, you'll need to use the following.

```
<ShimGeneration>
    </Clear>
    <Add TypeName="HelperClass"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

Lastly, if you wish to generate just shims for the non-generic you'll need to use the following.

```
<ShimGeneration>
    </Clear>
    <Add TypeName="HelperClass!"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

I don't believe you can generate shims for select versions of a generic class. So if you were hoping to generate ShimHelperClass but not ShimHelperClass, I believe you are out of luck.